# Using bash to parse .env file and inject it to command line

Tags: bash, unix, kubernetes, environment-variables, kubectl

I am using kubernetes and trying to call the following command:
`kubectl set env deployment/server A=a B=b ...etc`
My env variables are located in .env file, and each value can contain spaces, non-escaped chars, comments, empty lines and so on:

```
## Common variables
NODE_ENV=production


## Server variables
SERVER_PORT=8009
CORS_ORIGIN=https://www.example.io,http://www.example.io,http://localhost:3000
SESSION_SECRET=/qm%7HLw"pk(8@"pja#I9CbN#2Lg[%d>5{CDA_9g|ZvZmuZ$]=';EhA#g+C;1>&
```

I am trying to parse the .env file so that I can integrate it in the command:

```
kubectl set env deployment/server $(do magic with .env file to extract the escaped variables)
```

Tried `grep -v '^#' .env | xargs` but it doesn't work with characters that need escaping or quotes. My bash abilities are not the strongest right now. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @prd New to kubernetes and didn't find well toturial that explains how to write .yml configs. Currency doing everyting via cli and kubectl.

Comment: you can use configmap to load envs to your pod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat .env | grep -v '^#\|^$' | xargs -0 echo | tr '\n' ' '
```

This would print everything in one line: `NODE_ENV=production SERVER_PORT=8009 CORS_ORIGIN=https://www.example.io,http://www.example.io,http://localhost:3000 SESSION_SECRET=/qm%7HLw"pk(8@"pja#I9CbN#2Lg[%d>5{CDA_9g|ZvZmuZ$]=';EhA#g+C;1>&`

I am not sure if you need to keep the `VAR=` or if you also would like to get rid of that (pipe into `sed` or `awk` in the end then and replace it with whatever you need)

Comment: Thanks, this is a progress. I actually need the values escaped and wrapped with quotes since values contains slashes and quotes, this is the big issue. Any idea how to handle that?

Comment: `| sed 's/=/="/g' |  sed 's/ /" /g' ` this would add quotes to all your values. But you also need to look into your values and escape certain chars with a backslash \ ?

Comment: Exactly. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Yeah, you can use one complex sed or just chain several ones to maintain readability. First add a backslash to all $-chars, then to all %-chars...change the char to whatever you need. Use a backslash in case it also used in Regex to escape it or sed will interpret it as a regex flag.

`sed 's/\$/\\$/g' | sed 's/\%/\\%/g'`

If this is what you meant I will update my main answer to make it more readable.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it is something I can continue with.